# Delete other firebase authentication account and link that key to new authentication account

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I have two methods for signing in, email and password, and phone number. When I register using a phone number I create an account. Now I create another account with email. Upon updating the email account Profile I added a phone number that already exists in a different account. How can I delete that phone number account and linked that phone number to my current email account?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Would you like to delete an existing Firebase account?

Comment: I want to link another account to a new account but it gives me an error that the user is already linked to another account. So I wanted to delete that other account so that I can link it

Answer (score 1):

Since you say that you have two methods for signing in, a single user can create two accounts, one with a phone number, and one with an email and password. In this case, it really depends on which one would you like to be used as a primary authentication option. For example, if you want the phone authentication to be the primary option, once the user is authenticated, you can  [get the credentials](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/PhoneAuthProvider#getCredential(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) as explained in the official documentation on how to [create a PhoneAuthCredential object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#create-a-phoneauthcredential-object), and then simply call FirebaseUser's [linkWithCredential(AuthCredential credential)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#linkWithCredential(com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential)) method to link with email and password, for example. However, you can link that account with [any other available providers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking), like Google or Facebook.

If you need by chance a custom authentication system, then you should consider implementing this mechanism:

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth

So there is no need to delete any account, simply link it.

Comment: Hey Bilal. Can I help you with other information?